# Unicast/multicast packet using xdp/tc eBPF

Tags: bpf, ebpf, xdp-bpf

I am trying to design a load balancer using ebpf. I want to transmit the incoming packet to different destinations (devices connected in the same network). Although I have used the `clone_bpf_redirect()`  helper function to redirect the packet to real/ virtual interfaces and it's working fine, now I want to broadcast/unicast the packet to other devices connected in the same network.

XDP does not support it, as far as I know. Therefore, using tc bpf hook. Is there any helper function or which action should I use? Can anyone please guide me on how can I do this?

```
**eBpf load divider**: 192.168.98.178 (load divider)
**Receiver 1**: 192.168.98.131
**Receiver 2**: 192.168.98.138
```

```
    iph->daddr = htonl(3232260739);  //Dest: 192.168.98.131 
    iph->check = 0;
    iph->check = checksum((unsigned short *)iph, sizeof(struct iphdr));

    // Update upd packet checksum of 
    sum = old_daddr + (~ntohs(*(unsigned short *)&iph->daddr) & 0xffff);
    sum += ntohs(udp->check);
    sum = (sum & 0xffff) + (sum>>16);
    udp->check = htons(sum + (sum>>16) - 1);
// clone the packet and redirect to infdex 
    bpf_clone_redirect(skb,  skb->ifindex, 0);
//clone the packet and redirect to infdex (virtual interface 2)
    bpf_clone_redirect(skb,  skb->ifindex + 2, 0);
//clone the packet and redirect to infdex (virtual interface 4)
    bpf_clone_redirect(skb,  skb->ifindex + 4, 0);
            return TC_ACT_OK;
// Or
         //   return TC_ACT_REDIRECT;
```

```
sudo tc filter add dev ens33 ingress bpf da obj bpf_loadbalancer.o sec ingress
```

after this, I am getting the 1 packet to 3 different ifindex but I want to get the same packet to other devices connected into the network. How can I redirect the packet out of the device, not the interfaces?

Comment: I don't understand where the issue is. You can use `bpf_clone_redirect` from a tc-bpf program and send packets out on other devices.

Comment: bpf_clone_redirect(skb, skb->ifindex , 0);
or 
bpf_clone_redirect(skb, skb->ifindex + 1, 0);
this helper function redirect the traffic to the same device interface right?... i just want to forward the ingress packet to another device connected in the same network.

Comment: let's assume the scenario we have 4 devices connected in the network,  bpf program is only running on the device 1 and device 2 sends the msg "hello" to device 1. In response device 1 send the "hello" message to device 3 and device 4. I don't know how could I redirect the message to other devices, not the interface of device 1. just want to implement unicast/multicast.

Comment: No, this helper can redirect to other devices as well according to documentation: https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/bpf-helpers.7.html.

Comment: sorry, i am not too good in programming. could you please help me how could I send the packed to other device using bpf_clone_redirect?

Comment: int bpf_clone_redirect(struct sk_buff *skb, u32 ifindex, u64 flags) i am calling this function as bpf_clone_redirect(skb, skb->ifindex, 0).... my question is where should i add the destionain address in this helper?

Comment: Don't you already have a piece of code from which you can work? (`Although I have used the clone_bpf_redirect helper function to redirect the packet to real/ virtual interfaces and its working fine.`) You need to change the address in the packet before you redirect it to the device. You can find examples in the Linux source code, under `samples/bpf/`.

Comment: I am new using BPF, but AFAIK you could create a map `BPF_MAP_TYPE_DEVMAP` and store all your ifindex that you want to redirect. When you receive the packet from your specific interface entrypoint, you could redirect to all interface that are stored in your map using only one call, `bpf_redirect_map()`.

Comment: i have added the chunk of code in my question, please guide me .. Thanks