# multicast or broadcast the packet using eBPF tc hook

Tags: bpf, ebpf, xdp-bpf

I am trying to design a load balancer using `ebpf`. I want to redirect the incoming packet to different destinations. Although I have used the **bpf_clone_redirect** helper function to redirect the packet to real/ virtual interfaces and it's working fine. Now I want to redirect the packet to multiple interfaces at once.
Here is the piece of code I write to redirect the 1 packet.

```
    eth->h_dest[0] = 0xb8;
    eth->h_dest[1] = 0x27;
    eth->h_dest[2] = 0xeb;
    eth->h_dest[3] = 0x42;
    eth->h_dest[4] = 0x77;
    eth->h_dest[5] = 0x56;
new_port = ntohs( 5302) ; 
udp->dest= new_port;          //change the destination port

ipaddr = htonl(0xc0a8006c);  // Dest: 192.168.98.108 
iph->daddr = ipaddr;         // Change the destination address 

// Calculate the sum_diff for destination address and Port number

sum = bpf_csum_diff((void *)&old1_daddr , 4,(void *)&ipaddr,4 ,  0);
sum1 = bpf_csum_diff((void *)&old_port , 4,(void *)&new_port,4 ,  0);


ipaddr2 = htonl(0xc0a8006e);  // Dest: 192.168.98.110
iph->daddr = ipaddr2;         // Change the destination address 

//L3 and L4 checksum Update

bpf_l3_csum_replace(skb, IP_CSUM_OFF,  0 , sum,0 );
bpf_l4_csum_replace(skb, UDP_CSUM_OFF , 0, sum +sum1, IS_PSEUDO | sizeof(ipaddr) );

bpf_clone_redirect(skb,  skb->ifindex, 0 ); // Packet forward to the destination 

//Repeat the same functionality 

// Calculate the sum_diff for destination address and Port number

sum = bpf_csum_diff((void *)&old1_daddr , 4,(void *)&ipaddr2,4 ,  0);

//L3 and L4 checksum Update

bpf_l3_csum_replace(skb, IP_CSUM_OFF,  0 , sum,0 );
bpf_l4_csum_replace(skb, UDP_CSUM_OFF , 0, sum, IS_PSEUDO | sizeof(ipaddr2) );

bpf_clone_redirect(skb,  skb->ifindex, 0 ); // Packet forward to the destination 

return TC_ACT_OK;
```

I am facing the problem to update the MAC address of packet. With the above code i can change the destination address and port number but unable to updat2 the mac address in 2nd clone.

Comment: Same comments as for [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63997103/unicast-multicast-packet-using-xdp-tc-ebpf). Just call `bpf_clone_redirect()` multiple times, after updating IP destination and checksums if necessary.

Comment: Dear @Qeole, yes i can call it multiple times and forward to same destination multiple times  but for each time i wants to update the new  destination address. I don't know how to add another destination address at the same time.
For example the packet came in and i want to make 2 copies of it and forward it to two destinations ***192.168.0.108*** and ***192.168.0.110**. Currently i can only forward it to 1 destination.

Comment: Edit the destination address in your packet header to change it to ...108, call the helper, edit to change to ...110, then call the helper again? You have the code to change IP and clone once already, just repeat the whole process for your second destination? (You probably want to fold that into an inline function to avoid writing the same code a second time, but it's not mandatory.) I case it was what bothers you, note that `bpf_clone_redirect()` clones and sends your packet when you call the helper, with the address it has at that time. It does not wait for your program to return to do so.

Comment: Could you retry with verbose and put the output somewhere (or paste the last few lines here)?

Comment: @Qeole I tried to repeat the whole function again after *bpf_clone_redirect(). it complies properly. When i tried to load the flie to tc hook the i got this error message.  The error message can see in edit question.

Comment: @pchaigno sorry for that :)